# SDN relation is not removed

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I want to implement a time tree in neo4j using spring-data-neo4j.
The following graph displays the time tree, which is currently only containing the Root Node (223) and the years 2016 and 2018.

[image: Example tree with two years]

If i would add 2017 now i want the result 2016-[:next]->2017->[:next]->2018 and the next-relation between 2016 and 2018 to be removed.

This should be achieved by the createChild method of the root node:

```
public TimeNode createChild(int value) {
    TimeNode newChild = new Year();
    newChild.setValue(value);

    if (!this.hasChildren()) {
        this.setFirstChild(newChild);
        this.setLastChild(newChild);
    } else if (this.getFirstChild().getValue() > value) {
        //new node is first child
        newChild.setNextNode(this.getFirstChild());
        this.setFirstChild(newChild);
    } else if (this.getLastChild().getValue() < value) {
        //new node is last child
        newChild.setPreviousNode(this.getLastChild());
        this.setLastChild(newChild);
    } else {
        TimeNode previous = this.getFirstChild();
        TimeNode next = this.getLastChild();
        for (TimeNode current : this.getChildren()) {
            if (current.getValue() < value){
                if (current.getValue() > previous.getValue()) previous = current;
            }
            else if (current.getValue() < next.getValue()) next = current;
        }
        System.out.println("Previous is "+previous.getValue());
        System.out.println("Next is "+next.getValue());
        newChild.setPreviousNode(previous);
        newChild.setNextNode(next);
    }
    this.addChild(newChild);
    return newChild;
}
```

By the console output i can confirm, that previous and next are set to 2016 and 2018. nextNode and previousNode are declared as follows:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Relationship(type = "NEXT")
private TimeNode nextNode = null;

@JsonIgnore
@Relationship(type = "NEXT", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private TimeNode previousNode = null;
```

After creating the new childNode, i call

```
timeNodeRepository.save(foundYear,2);
```

in the calling service. The Repository is the standard repository

```
@Repository
public interface TimeNodeRepository extends GraphRepository<TimeNode>
```

But when i use this code to add the node 2017, i end up with a graph as i wish PLUS an extra "next"-relation between 2016 and 2018 (so this was not removed).

How can i force the graph to REPLACE the nextNode of 2016 instead of adding another one?

[image: I might add that previousNode and ne]xtNode are set both for a relation:

I might add that setNextNode also sets the previous node:

```
public void setNextNode(TimeNode nextNode) {
    this.nextNode=null;
    if (nextNode==null) return;
    nextNode.previousNode = this;
    this.nextNode = nextNode;
}
```

setPreviousNode works vice versa.

Comment: If you have a relationship being persisted that you don't expect, it is generally because one of your objects is still holding a reference to another object that you're not aware of or haven't accounted for in your code. Did you check that your linked list is correct, both forwards and backwards, before being saved?

Comment: I did not perform a check there, but the setters should deal with that. It seems, that an entity class will map a related note rather in the wrong direction instead of leaving it null, could that be possible?

Comment: Could you add how you configure and manage transactions? Loading foundYear and saving it must be inside 1 transaction.

Comment: Sure, it happens in this service: https://github.com/DonAscon/graphEndpoint/blob/master/src/main/java/graphEndpoint/dataConnection/TimeTree/TimeTreeService.java